# How can I make typescript restrict array type based on filter inference?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, tsconfig

This will never fail to return an array of strings:

```
(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => arr.filter(item => item !== undefined);
```

<sub>[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwTmBcAEwM4BcwEsB2BzaAfaBXVAJgKYBmaRBAlANoC6lMiKGd0AvAHzThgB0ZAGwREwwZMIC27LuKJSAhGzZ5CpclQDcQA)</sub>

But TypeScript does not accept to compile this because it doesn't infer that the filter predicate will return `true` if and only `item` is a string. Explicitly typing the predicate doesn't seem to help either:

```
const predicate = (item: string | undefined): item is string => item !== undefined;
(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => arr.filter(item => predicate(item));
```

<sub>[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJwKYBMCWwCGUkwLwwAUaOAtgFwzQJpgDmMAPjAK5gpIBmtqAlJSSSkYaCFSg16+AHwiyMAIR4CbDtzCoA3AChCmBAkqFqtBs1VceKXgG0Auv3GS69mTH0IAdNwA2OBMTyeLKIqBjYSIFCvLw6QA)</sub>

This works but is much wordier (and if I'm not mistaken, much slower):

```
(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => {
    const ret: string[] = [];
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (item !== undefined) {
            ret.push(item);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

<sub>[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwTmBcAEwM4BcwEsB2BzaAfaBXVAJgKYBmaRBAlANoC6lMiKGd0AvAHzQDeAUNAOgBjAPapE0MEQSMkadKzbQ6Abn6CSIsLFHiE0ZAiIBbaCJLRwYSj3WDByC8EMnoAQjZL8xMqgo2+eyDBKQQAOgAHXDgAC2cjY0o1YIEAXztodPtQ3DBUSWk1VKA)</sub>

Is there an experimental flag I can enable in my `tsconfig.json` that'll enable TypeScript to make type inferences based on the `.filer` predicate?

Comment: I'm surprised because I just used this feature in a part of my AoC solution today. Let me take a look...

Comment: You should use `predicate` instead of `item => predicate(item)`.  You can also make it [generic](https://tsplay.dev/N9pGJw) and use it if you're going to use it often.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541957/2887218 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64759304/2887218 for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an anonymous inline function instead of the predicate:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJwKYBMCWwCGUkwLwwAUaOAtgFwzQJpgDmMAPjAK5gpIBmtqAlJSSSkYaCFSg16+AHwiyMAIR4CbDtzCoA3AFgAUHsKYECSoWq0GzVVx4peAbQC6-cZLpOZMIwgB03ADY4CMTyeLKIqBjYSCFCvLyaMAD0STBIxiAIegbepuZSVuw2GnZOLvnujp7efmiB6YQR6Fg4CcmpIADW2bopImD+PPDIzdE5xnkSFkysRep8ZZQVHmFexrX1wbGkLoLCoq7Tq3uKyrNqtglAA)

```ts
const predicate = (item: string | undefined): item is string => item !== undefined;

(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => arr.filter(item => predicate(item)); // error

(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => arr.filter(predicate); // ok

// inline predicate
(arr: (string | undefined)[]): string[] => arr.filter((item): item is string => item !== undefined);
```

Comment: Ah, great! Guess I should have been more lax about [this Jake Archibald's advice](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/function-callback-risks/)

Comment: Mr Archibald did say "unless they're designed for it", and you designed it yourself

Comment: @NinoFiliu Added inline predicate, too